# An adapter for GridView with 2 type of view (android)

Tags: android, gridview

I want to make an adapter for GridView with 2 type of View accoding to the item position.
The first item for the Grid must be in a View of 1 column and the others items in a View of 2 column. I dont't know if i must custom the GridView or just make it in adapter.
This is an example of the result that i want
[image: Example of one I want]

PLEASE I NEED YOUR HELP

Answer (score 0):

This isn't likely the answer you want to hear, but the easiest way to do this is to use a `ListView` instead of a `GridView`. You have 2 distinct row types, 1 element and 2 element. Use standard `ListView` conventions to have two different row types present.

To accomplish this, create a new `Adapter` that extends one of the list adapter classes, override `getView(int, View, Viewgroup)` so that it returns the correct view based on position (the first argument), and then have it return the correct view for each item in your list. You'll have to manage the relationship between entries in the list and whether they're wide or normal, but that shouldn't be too big of a deal.

Comment: Thank you @Travis for your answer, but if i use ListView can i get a result which look like that? If yes, give me an example of code please.

Comment: Also these element must be clikable and an element represents an item in the adapter.

Comment: Yes, you have to create two different types of rows, one row with 1 element that spans both of the ideal columns, and one row with two columns. I'm not going to implement it for you though.

Comment: Ok thank you all the same. I'm trying to resolve my problems with your indications